# Could not find Angular protractor /cli.js file on mac was told check how I Installed Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, protractor

I have a massive headache trying to find protractor/built/cli.js file in protractor.  I would really appreciate a second opinion.

To locate the cli.js file,  I did the following syntax.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
```

I was expecting to find a protractor file in this location. However, I didn't.  So I spoke to a person helping me with the protractor in this [video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bd9ltgcwvwqz647/Testrunner%20update%20.mp4?dl=0).

I clearly outlined the problem and what I was experiencing.

The response was asked '*how did I installed protractor?*'  I told him I installed protractor the standard way using npm install -g protractor command.

His response was '*if installed it should show in node modules*'.  This response is very confusing to me.

I don't understand what he is trying to say because it's not in nodes modules

So my question is pretty straightforward:

**1.**  Should I run the npm install -g protractor command again so I can find the location?

**2.** If 1 is not a good idea, how to do I find the protractor file so I can find the cli.js file location so I can run my angular test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Because you install protractor as global package, you need to figure out the install folder path for global package via executing following cmd: `npm prefix -g`

It will print out a folder path which is the global package install folder. Then you can find `build/cli.js` from

`<global package install folder>/lib/node_modules/protractor/build/cli.js`

[image]

Comment: Hi I think I've found it.  I did npm  prefix -g and then with a bit of investigating I found: 



`Users/my_user_name/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js`

Is this correct?

Comment: The path looks correct.  If the `cli.js` can be found in above folder. It should be the answer.